# Multiple date manipulations on pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which I need to filter by dates. For example, sample of my dataset is given below:

**df:**

```py
        id      date        time        promo   Wave    
1373662 2702    2019-10-20  10:11:58    7560    C   
1553376 2702    2019-10-20  10:11:58    8859    C   
49686   2274    2019-10-11  20:39:29    2976    A   
398860  2274    2019-10-11  20:39:29    5413    B   
506767  2987    2019-10-30  20:52:46    8533    C   
916306  2987    2019-10-30  20:52:46    9447    D   
1234493 2816    2019-10-14  13:12:50    6470    A   
1415534 2816    2019-10-14  13:12:50    5888    A   
381483  2334    2019-10-24  14:20:29    9318    D   
1217261 2334    2019-10-24  14:20:29    0573    F
```

All IDs are supposed to get promos based on Waves (A-F order)
I want to check if any IDs got the promos in a different order. For example, getting wave F before A or Wave B before A and so on.

I am unable to come up with a query that can do that. What I have done is sort the dataset by id, date, time. However, since there are 2M+ rows, it is hard to check where the discrepancy occurs.

```py
df.sort_values(by=['id','date','time'],inplace=True]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the list of `id`s that this happens, assuming that your `df` is ordered as you mention.

The [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) will transform the characters to numbers (`wave_num`), the [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) will calculate the difference between the `wave_num` and then you just need to see for which `id` the difference is negative

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2,2,4],
                   'wave':['C','A','A','B','C','A']})
df['wave_num'] = df['wave'].apply(lambda x: ord(x))
df['difference'] = df.groupby('id')['wave_num'].diff()
list(df.loc[(df.difference<0)]['id'].unique())
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

```
# once this is done
df.sort_values(by=['id','date','time'], inplace=True)

# create two columns
df["wave_ordered"] = df[["id", "Wave"]].groupby(["id"])["Wave"].transform(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
df["is_ordered"] = df["wave_ordered"].transform(lambda x: x.split() == sorted(x.split()))
```

The column `is_ordered`gives you an indication of whether the individual had promos in the "right" order or not.

In order to identify individuals presenting discrepancies, all you then have to do is:

```
set(df[df["is_ordered"] == False]["id"])
```